# xampp and numpy: ImportError : DLL load failed in my Apache log error

Tags: python, apache, numpy, xampp, importerror

I'm trying to run a python script, from my webapp using xampp (Apache). But I've an issue when I'm importing numpy. 
I don't know why, I can't import this library, while I installed python via anaconda for all users.
Below you can see the Apache (error.log):

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy__init__.py", line 140, in 
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy_distributor_init.py", line 34, in 
    from . import _mklinit
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

If someone have an idea to solve this issue,please?

Thanks in advance